# Objection.js Stubbing Chained "whereIn" methods with Sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon, knex.js, objection.js

Trying to stub a chained knex query using Sinon. The query looks like the following

```
const result = await TableModel
  .query()
  .whereIn('id', idList)
  .whereIn('value', valueList);
```

Normally I use a helper function that I created that returns an instance of the model with each method stubbed to return `this`, like so

```
for (const method of ['query', 'whereIn']) {
  TableModel[method] = sandbox.stub().returnsThis();
}
```

Then stubbing the instance within the test to resolve the necessary test case

```
TableModel.whereIn = sandbox.stub().resolves({ object: 'stuff' });
```

However, this doesn't work when chaining the same method I'm getting an error from mocha / chai / sinon that reads

> TypeError: TableModel.query(...).whereIn(...).whereIn is not a function

Looking for help on how to stub and resolve the method within the test.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to stub similar scenario:

`await model.query().findById();`

and I was able to stub this in following way:

```
const stubbedData = { ... }; // Whatever you want to get

sandbox.stub(Model, 'query').returns({
  findById: sandbox.stub().returns(stubbedData),
});
```

In your case it will be very similar and if you need to distinguish between two `whereIn` then you can use `withArgs` or first `whereIn` could return another "nested" stub.

Here is a good article about stubbing complex objects:

https://codeutopia.net/blog/2016/05/23/sinon-js-quick-tip-how-to-stubmock-complex-objects-such-as-dom-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution, you can use `stub.withArgs(arg1[, arg2, ...]);` solve this.

`tableModel.js`:

```js
const TableModel = {
  query() {
    return this;
  },
  async whereIn(field, values) {
    return "real data";
  },
};

module.exports = TableModel;
```

`main.js`:

```js
const TableModel = require("./tableModel");

async function main(idList, valueList) {
  const result = await TableModel.query()
    .whereIn("id", idList)
    .whereIn("value", valueList);

  return result;
}

module.exports = main;
```

`main.test.js`:

```js
const main = require("./main");
const TableModel = require("./tableModel");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("50957424", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it("should pass", async () => {
    sinon.stub(TableModel);
    TableModel.query.returnsThis();
    TableModel.whereIn.withArgs("id").returnsThis();
    TableModel.whereIn.withArgs("value").resolves({ object: "stuff" });
    const actual = await main([1, 2], ["a", "b"]);
    expect(actual).to.be.eql({ object: "stuff" });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(TableModel.query);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(TableModel.whereIn.firstCall, "id", [1, 2]);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(TableModel.whereIn.secondCall, "value", ["a", "b"]);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  50957424
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (16ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |       92 |      100 |    66.67 |       92 |                   |
 main.js       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 main.test.js  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 tableModel.js |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |               3,6 |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/50957424